# Why is this Flex 4 Transition not working?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml, flex-spark

I have a test application [here](http://queirozf.com/exampleFlashBuilder/bin-debug/exampleFlashBuilder.html) which was made using the following code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

            public function comboBoxHandler():void{
                var selectedItem:String = showComboBox.selectedItem;

                if(selectedItem == "All results"){
                    currentState = "default";
                    return;
                }else if(selectedItem == "Only results within tags"){
                    currentState = "tagInput";
                    return;
                }
            }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>    
<s:states>
    <s:State name="default"/>
    <s:State name="tagInput"/>
</s:states>
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition id="showTagTextInput" fromState="default" toState="tagInput">
        <s:Sequence id="t1p1" targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput,GoButton]}">

            <s:Move  duration="700"/>
            <s:Fade  duration="400"/>

        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
    <s:Transition id="hideTagTextInput" fromState="tagInput" toState="default">
        <s:Sequence id="t2p1" targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput,GoButton]}" >

            <s:Fade  duration="400"/>
            <s:Move  duration="700"/>

        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>

</s:transitions>

<s:Label x="136" y="13" width="120" height="34" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="15"
             text="Lessons&#xd;Learnt" textAlign="center"/>

    <s:Group id="group" width="100%" height="100%"
             x.default="0" y.default="55" width.default="400" height.default="231"
             y.tagInput="55" height.tagInput="256">
        <s:Label x="45" y="38" width="50" height="22" text="Search" textAlign="center"
                 verticalAlign="middle"/>
        <s:TextInput x="103" y="38" width="193"
                     useHandCursor.tagInput="false"/>
        <s:Label x="45" y="89" width="51" height="22" text="Show" textAlign="center"
                 verticalAlign="middle"/>
        <s:Button id="GoButton" x="253" y="137" width="43" label="Go" useHandCursor="true"
                  buttonMode="true" mouseChildren="false"
                  x.tagInput="254" y.tagInput="188"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="showComboBox" x="104" y="89" width="192" change="comboBoxHandler();"
                    selectedIndex="0">
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>All results</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Only results within tags</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:DropDownList>
        <s:Label id="tagsLabel" includeIn="tagInput" x="104" y="146" width="61" height="20" text="Tags"
                 textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
        <s:TextInput id="tagsTextInput" includeIn="tagInput" x="173" y="146" width="123"/>

    </s:Group>
```

You can check, by **clicking the link** I gave, that this app performs some basic transition effect **when you select different options from the DropDownBox**.

The first (show) transition doesn't work so well, but the second (hide) transition does.

Does anyone know how to fix that? In the first transition, I would like the button to slide down **first**, only after that should the text input fade In. **Why isn't this working?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show all your code?  I believe the problem is with the states/component defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to point particular effect target rather that pointing all the targets in `<s:Sequence />`. So place targets to `<s:Move />` and `<s:Fade />`. Also you can perform additional transitions tuning by placing `<s:AddAction />` and `<s:RemoveAction />` with corresponding targets to point a place within sequence where transition should invoke `includeIn` and `excludeFrom` states declarations.

So these transitions works fine with your code:

```
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="default" id="showTagTextInput" toState="tagInput">
        <s:Sequence id="t1p1">
            <s:Move duration="700" targets="{[GoButton]}" />
            <s:AddAction targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}" />
            <s:Fade duration="400" targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
    <s:Transition fromState="tagInput" id="hideTagTextInput" toState="default">
        <s:Sequence id="t2p1">
            <s:Fade duration="400" targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}" />
            <s:RemoveAction targets="{[tagsLabel,tagsTextInput]}" />
            <s:Move duration="700" targets="{[GoButton]}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

Comment: I agree about spreading the targets among the actual actions. But I didn't quite get why the piece of code isn't working when I explicitly defined the order I wanted the transitions to happen. I don't get why the code shown does not create the desired effect.

Comment: Worked very well... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it's because your tag input is only being included in the tagInput state, but the alpha is 100% and there's no transition between the states.  Try this:

```
<s:Label id="tagsLabel" alpha.default="0" alpha.tagInput="100" x="104" y="146" width="61" height="20" text="Tags" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
<s:TextInput id="tagsTextInput" alpha.default="0" alpha.tagInput="100" x="173" y="146" width="123"/>
```

You might also want to set visible to false during 'default' state.  Also, what Constantiner said is true.